# load listbox value to multivalue listbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

am having a list box now i have to convert to  multi value list-box so this is the value of listbox ..i know if i want multiple value mean in html it can done by Multiple="true" but now i have to convert listbox to multivale listbox ..by selection id ="outlet"....

```
<select size="8" id="outlet">
    <option value="A K AZAD ROAD REHABARI GUWAHATI">A K AZAD ROAD REHABARI GUWAHATI</option>
    <option value="ACCENTURE-HYD">ACCENTURE-HYD</option>
    <option value="ADLABS-HYDERABAD">ADLABS-HYDERABAD</option>
    <option value="AIRPORT GUWAHATI">AIRPORT GUWAHATI</option>
    <option value="AIRPORT RAIPUR">AIRPORT RAIPUR</option>
    <option value="AIRPORT VIZAG">AIRPORT VIZAG</option>
    </select>
```

how to achieve this.....????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
$("#outlet").attr("multiple","true");
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jd8X4/